# How to separate vector coming together

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image][image]i'm importing a svg vector, that is separated, but Blender puts them together, any ideas on how I could separate them in blender?

I'm a TOTAL newbie, second day using blender.

Comment: Please provide some screenshots and/or blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: And what should be separated? I've upvoted your question so you can add more images.

Comment: I tryed what Firewill said so, but still, all together. The letters, I need them separated.

Answer (score 0):

Go into edit mode, select all vertices using  <kbd>A</kbd>  the press  <kbd>P</kbd>  and from the dropdown menu select by loose parts, now you have every item in a different object.

Adittionally you can press   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd>  to reset the origin to the geometry average.

Comment: I tryed, but they still together.

Comment: I'm positive what I described works, double check you are in the correct mode, and that you are selecting the correct options, if that doesn't work consider postign the file.

Comment: I'm very new at blenders and here, I'm  trying to post the file, but it just won't go.. stays on the page, saying that might take loing time, but it doesn't go.

Comment: are you using this uploader https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?
You have to click upload to begin the upload process.

Comment: There's a button to hit when that message is on the screen, Bruno.  That tripped me up before

Answer (score 0):

My friend there, Firewill almost got it all right, in my case, I could not press A, to select all, because they were still staying together. Perhaps, his way works for others.

Go into edit mode, you are going to see the curves, click in one of the curves from the object you want,  then press L, and make sure all the object you want is selected, than press P and from the dropdown menu select separate parts.

Then, I got one letter separated, I just need to do the same on all of them.